# Security Access Restrictions: display a blank out-of-browser application window

Tags: c#, security, silverlight, ssl

I am working on a [Trusted Applications application based on Silverlight5](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/evalcenter/ee721083(v=vs.80)):

> System administrators can configure computers to prevent users from
>   installing or running out-of-browser applications that require
>   elevated trust.
>
> If installing trusted applications is disabled, attempting to install
>   one will have no effect. In this case, trusted applications that are
>   already installed (or are installed by the administrator) will work
>   correctly.
>
> If running trusted applications is disabled, attempting to run one
>   will display a blank out-of-browser application window. Typically,
>   however, if running trusted applications is disabled, installing them
>   will also be disabled.

I need to do the local files access and IO operations, so far I have tried following options:

1. Suggestions from [Group Policy Settings](http://www.microsoft.com/GetSilverlight/resources/documentation/grouppolicysettings.aspx#TrustedApplcations)
2. IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
3. Trust Elevated, Out of Browser Install and In Browser with Elevated Trust.

Since I still face this issue in my application, let me know if there is any further alternative which can address this specific problem:

> If running trusted applications is disabled, attempting to run one
>   will display a blank out-of-browser application window.

NOTE: I may not get reverted the global policy deployed by the system administrator. Hence looking for a workaround instead.

Comment: The whole point of administrator policy is that you can't bypass it.

Comment: Is there an option to get/use some JavaScript support for file IO, specific to this case of Silverlight? Just in case you know. Can that bypass the policy?

Comment: Javascript cannot write to local disk.  You're specifically asking to defeat the entire purpose of security policy.  You can't do that.